# Kotlintest not executing test when using springmockk

Tags: spring, unit-testing, kotlin, mockk, kotlintest

I tried to write an integration test for my kotlin spring application.
For this I am using the kotlintest framework. As I need to mock one of the beans in my application I also added mockk with the springmockk extension. After adding the springmockk extension the test no longer got executed.

I noticed this happens as soon as springmockk is added to the gradle testImplement dependencies, it does not even have to be imported in the application code itself.

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.21'
    ext.kotlintestVersion='3.4.2'
    ext.spring_boot_version='2.1.4.RELEASE'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:$springBoot_version")
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-allopen:$kotlin_version")
    }
}

...

dependencies {
    ...
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:$springBoot_version") {
    testImplementation("io.kotlintest:kotlintest-runner-junit5:$kotlintestVersion")
    testImplementation("io.kotlintest:kotlintest-extensions-spring:$kotlintestVersion")
    testImplementation("io.mockk:mockk:1.9.3")
//    testImplementation("com.ninja-squad:springmockk:2.0.0")
}
```

On github I found an issue which sadly has been closed already without any proper way of using these two frameworks together: https://github.com/Ninja-Squad/springmockk/issues/26

Edit:

This is an example test, which is working when using mockkito but not when using springmockk.

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension::class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@WithMockUser(authorities = ["ROLE_TESTUSER"])
internal class MockTest : AnnotationSpec() {

    override fun listeners() = listOf(SpringListener)

    @Autowired
    lateinit var mockMvc: MockMvc

    @MockkBean
    lateinit var securityHelper: SecurityHelper

    @Test
    fun integrationTest() {
        whenever(securityHelper.someFunction()).thenReturn("test")
        mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/some/endpoint")
        ).andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk)
    }
}
```

`./gradlew test --rerun-tasks` output:

```
> Configure project :
Property 'app.env' not found using profile dev: use -Papp.env=dev to define the environment for 'SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE'

> Task :compileKotlin

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 56s
5 actionable tasks: 5 executed
```

Comment: Could you show us an example of a test you tried to write?

Comment: And if there's any errors on running the tests, that would be very helpful too!

Comment: the error messages says you are missing `app.env` property from `application.yml` file

Answer (score 1):

#### Mock Bean with springMockk

To use `@MockkBean` you need to add [springmockk](https://github.com/Ninja-Squad/springmockk) and remove mockito core from the spring-boot-starter-test in your gradle file like:

```kotlin
testImplementation("io.mockk:mockk:1.9.3")
testImplementation("com.ninja-squad:springmockk:2.0.2")
testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test") {
    exclude(module = "mockito-core")
}
```

Then your bean should be mocked with:

```kotlin
@MockkBean
lateinit var securityHelper: SecurityHelper
```

#### Mock Bean with MockK only

You can mock the bean just using mockK by modifying the `@TestConfiguration` and setting the profile of the mock Bean to be the same as the one used for your test:

```
  @TestConfiguration
  class ControllerTestConfig {

    @Bean
    @Profile("test")
    fun securityHelper(): SecurityHelper {
      val securityHelperMock: SecurityHelper = mockk(relaxed = true)
      every { securityHelperMock.someFunction() } returns "test"
      return securityHelperMock
    }
  }
```

You can force use the TestConfig by putting it in your `@SpringBootTest`:

```
@SpringBootTest(
    classes = [YourApplication::class, ControllerTestConfig::class]
)
```